# Subquery with IN operator to list Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to do a Subquery in Entity Framework using IN operator, then, using as list and send to the view.

This is my SQL code

```
select * from famProd where id in (Select famID from appNfam where appID = 1)
```

and this is my controller

```
public ActionResult ProductFamily(int id)
    {
        Session["appID"] = id;

        var famProds = from prodFam in famProd where prodFam.id == (from piv in appNfam where piv.appID  == id);



        return View();

    }
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: Please show classes etc. This can probably be done much simpler by using navigation properties.

Comment: Why don't you create a stored procedure in database and just consume that here. For nested queries, it's always better to handle them from database side, much quicker.

Comment: @Dash, I made a stored procedure and works incredible, also I tried the other 2 solutions but none of them work. 

Thank you.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Sometimes it doesn't worth the time you are spending finding a solution in Front-end which easily can be done in back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :-

```
var appIds   = from piv in appNfam where piv.appID  == id;
var famProds = from p in DbContext.famProd
            where appIds.Contains(p.id)
            select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
DbContext.appNfam.Where(piv => piv.app != null).Select(piv => piv.app)
```

Where app is:

```
public class appNfam
{ ...
    [ForeignKey("appID")] // Or set it in configuration
    public virtual famProd app {get; set;}
}
```